# How much of the success of the Soviet forces in WWII can be attributed to the modernization efforts enacted by the Soviet/Bolshevik leadership?

Tags: world-war-two, russian-revolution

The Bolsheviks took power in 1917 and were able to achieve significant progress in the industrialization and militarization of the country.  Even to the point that Hitler said,
“Had I known they had as many tanks as that, I’d have thought twice before invading.” [link to quote](http://www.oocities.org/weiwen_sg/voices.htm)

It's been argued that, during the end of 1941, Russia's unpaved roads and "general mud" slowed the German advance.  Early in the war the Russians lacked schooling in mobile warfare but as they learned it from the Germans the Industrialization that began under the Bolsheviks gave them the material they needed to win the war.

How much of the success of the Soviet forces in WWII can be attributed to the modernization efforts enacted by the Soviet/Bolshevik leadership? How different was the country's indutrialization trajectory under the Soviets than under the Tsars?

Comment: Criticism 1: "Many Tzars tried but failed to modernize Russia throughout its history." - Really? Many Tsars tried and succeeded. But did any Tsar try after 1850? I've read a bit of Russian history, and it seems to me that the last few Tsars were conservative and opposed modernization and modern concepts and continues to treat Russia and Russians as their personal property.

Comment: Criticism 2: But you are right that Russia did not modernize around the turn of the century. The lack of liberalization and modernization is in fact ofyen pointed out to be a major cause of the revolution. Hence, *had* the Tsars modernized the revolution would not have happened. Therefore, yes, the Russuans could have beaten WWII even without the Russian revolution, because that would have meant the *Tsar* had modernized Russia.

Comment: Since we are playing with counterfactuals in the comments (while claiming to be above said activity ;) I'll suggest that without the Russian Revolution WWII might not have even taken place...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: The industrialization under Stalin was in two five year plans, and was complete in 10 years. There is no way in heck to do this without a command economy, it's the only thing command economies are proven to do quickly and well, industrialize a pre-industrial economy. They did this is Russia, in China, and in Yugoslavia.

Comment: @RonMaimon - Google Peter the Great, as well as Katherine. Russia started industries - including military ones - under Tzars when they felt like it.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro just the opposite. The modernization was the cause of the revolution, without it revolution would be impossible. This is because the driving force behind revolution were industrial workers.

Comment: @Anixx false. The driving force were foreign backed agitators in the military and a few wealthy backroom socialists. The "proletariat" were just stirred up with promises of wealth, equality, and eternal riches poured on them by the benevolent state, and we all know how that worked out.

Comment: Given that the Germans were seen as liberators by many in the USSR initially, and their failures mostly attributed to their own policies of genocide and misguided military decisions from Berlin, the USSR won the war despite the Bolsheviks, not because of them.

Comment: @Anixx If you think that was true, then I must assume that all the Russian history you have read was written during communism. Even after superficial studies of Russian history it's completely obvious that most of the technical modernization came much later, mainly under Stalin. The political modernization has still not arrived.

Comment: I've edited my question.  Can this be reopened?

Comment: I think this is a valid quesiton. It's not as counterfactual as may seem, actually. For example, some of the power plants built by the Bolsheviks were actually built from detailed designs prepared under the Czar.

Comment: There is also World War I for comparison, which the Germans won against czarist Russia.

Comment: The Czarist state *did* modernize before WWI, and very successfully too. They just had a lot of ground to cover, and the Germans were better.  They were more than a match for the Austrians, however.  The upgrading and industrializing of Russia was a major headache for German war planners.

Comment: @Oldcat: (With tongue firmly in cheek) Even the Italians and Turks were better than the Austrians. Even the Serbs were better than the Austrians, until overcome by sheer numbers.

Comment: Ignoring 6 months of *Sitzkrieg* in winter of '39-'40, it took 21 months for the U.S. to enter WW II. It took 39 months for the U.S. to enter WW I. That additional 18 months from spring 1916 to fall 1917 is the period in which Germany overcame Russian forces. If U.S. forces had been landing in France in spring 1917, replacing the mutinous French army, the Germans would have had much less success on the Eastern Front that summer and fall.

Comment: Actually, the Italians weren't better than the Austrians, since they repeatedly lost to them in the dozen battles on the Isonzo.